# How to define parameter to class constructor before creating a instance with dependency injection

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, restsharp

I have a situation about dependency injection. There is a class in my project that I need and it's a member of another library (RestClient class of RestSharp lib.). I added that class in the start-up class as a transient but it has to take a parameter to its constructor before creating an instance. The problem is I don't know the parameter when the program initializes: because these parameters are changing according to the user's actions. I am searching for a way to define parameters to this class before creating an instance by the container. Is this design wrong? What should be the right design to solve this issue?

Added here image to better illustrate my question
[image]

Comment: I would 1) Create a class which can create RestClient instances using the correct configuration (this also tracks the user's actions, etc), 2) Register RestClient using a factory, which calls into that first class to get an instance to return

Comment: You dont need to pass the parameter here, you have to add like this `services.AddTransient<IRestClient, Restclient>();`. Where you have to create an interface `IRestClient` and implement the interface in your `RestClient` class. Sorry my bad, you can use ``services.AddTransient<Restclient>();``

Comment: Please add code as text and not as an image.

Comment: @canton7 I have modified my comment.

Comment: @viveknuna Stick with `IRestClient`, RestSharp also has one of them and it should definitely be used to support testability later on.

Comment: It's worth noting that if you do that, and use the `RestClient` parameterless ctor, you'll need to set `BaseUrl` later on after you've fetched an instance

Comment: @DavidG sorry I don't have an idea of RestSharp. I have provided the concept.

Comment: @Emre is your problem solved by my answer?

Comment: @viveknuna actually it's working when I use it as you said. However it's not what I want exactly, I need to pass a parameter to the constructor before an instance created. İf I use factory for RestClient Class it's working as I want. But I need more study to make sure ı have done it right.